# Первый и последний индекс последовательности элементов

Tags: python, циклы

Мне нужно подсчитывать сколько раз максимум подряд встречаеться орел и вывести первый и последний индекс максимальной последовательности

```
monets = []
for i in range(20):
    choices = ['Tails', 'Eagle']
    monets.append(random.choice(choices))
i = 0
cnt = 0
prev = 0
while i < len(monets):
    if monets[i] == 'Eagle':
        cnt += 1
        if monets[i] == 'Eagle' and i == len(monets) - 1 and prev < cnt:
            prev = cnt
    elif monets[i] != 'Eagle':
        if prev < cnt:
            prev = cnt
        cnt = 0
    i += 1

print(monets)
print(prev)
```

Посчитать сколько раз максимум встречаеться орел у меня вроде получилось, хотя и с небольшими трудностями, но вот совсем не пойму как посчитать первый и последний индекс максимальной последовательности Орлов

Comment: Ну как. Взять и запомнить в переменную )

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ